# Use list of index's to create a subset df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So i have a dataframe which ive selected certain values from :

`x=df[df['column'].str.contains('foo')].index`

if i then want to make a new df with the selected indexs from the original df by:
`df2=df[x]`,
the following message pops up:

`KeyError: "Int64Index([   48,    64,    98,   118,   120,   128,   138,   144,   151,\n              166,\n            ...\n            15892, 15893, 15894, 15895, 15896, 15897, 15898, 15899, 15900,\n            15901],\n           dtype='int64', length=4711) not in index"`

those indexs are in the dataframe as `df.iloc[48]` returns a value

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: need `df2=df.loc[x]`

Comment: cheers mate, that sorted it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - select by index values:

```
x=df.index[df['column'].str.contains('foo')]

df2=df.loc[x]
#if default monotonic index - 0,1,..., len(df) - 1
#df2=df.iloc[x]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

x=df.index[df['F'].str.contains('b')]
print (x)
Int64Index([3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')

df2=df.loc[x]
print (df2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Simplier is use only:

```
df2=df[df['F'].str.contains('b')]
print (df2)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```